# How do I navigate between screens on selecting a dropdown value in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

There are multiple screens in my kivy app:
1. main screen, screen1, screen2, screen3 and screen4.

main screen has main-dropdown and sub-dropdown list. main-dropdown shows groups and on selecting a particular group, sub-dropdown shows screens associated with that group.

I want to navigate to a particular screen when selected from sub-dropdown list. My code doesn't show any error but I am not able to navigate to the selected screen. Please help.

doca.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, DictProperty

class windowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    values_dict = {'Group1':['Screen1', 'Screen2'],
              'Group2':['Screen3', 'Screen4']}

    sub_values = ListProperty()

    def values_update(self,text):
        self.sub_values = self.values_dict[text]
        if text != 'Select group type':
            self.ids.sub_drop.text = 'select ' + text + ' screen'
            return 'select ' + text + ' screen'

    def open_screen(self, text):        
        if text != 'select ' + self.ids.main_drop.text + ' screen':
            sm = windowManager()
            sm.current = text

class Screen1(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class Screen3(Screen):
    pass

class Screen4(Screen):
    pass

class appln(App):                
    def build(self):    
        return windowManager()            

if __name__=="__main__":
    appln().run()
```

appln.kv

```
<WindowManager>:
    MainScreen:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    Screen3:
    Screen4:


<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'

    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        Spinner:
            id: main_drop
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 200, 100
            pos_hint:{'top': 1}
            text: 'Select group type'
            values: root.values_dict.keys()
            on_text:
                root.values_update(self.text)

        Spinner:
            id: sub_drop
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 230, 100
            pos_hint:{'top': 1}
            values: root.sub_values
            on_text: root.open_screen(self.text)


<Screen1>:
    name: 'Screen1'
    Label:
        text: 'This is screen 1'

<Screen2>:
    name: 'Screen2'
    Label:
        text: 'This is screen 2'

<Screen3>:
    name: 'Screen3'
    Label:
        text: 'This is screen 3'

<Screen4>:
    name: 'Screen4'
    Label:
        text: 'This is screen 4'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainScreen` code, the line:

```
sm = windowManager()
```

is creating a new instance of `windowManager`, so any use of that instance will have no effect on the `windowManager` that is actually managing your `Screens`. To fix this, just use a reference to the correct `windowManager` by replacing that line with:

```
sm = self.manager
```